# Write Function and its parameters after de-mangling Android Audio Record Mangled C++ Function

Tags: android, c++, gcc, android-ndk, audio-recording

If the
**Mangled name** **:-**

```
_ZN7android11AudioRecordC1E14audio_source_tj14audio_format_tjiPFviPvS3_ES3_ii
```

**After Demangling:-**

```
android::AudioRecord::AudioRecord(audio_source_tunsigned intaudio_format_tunsigned intintvoid (*)(intvoid*void*)void*intint)
```

**and then-**

```
typedef void (***AudioRecordInit**)(void*, int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int,int, void (*)(int, void *, void *), void*, int, int);
```

**Now Problem is
 new Mangled name:-**

```
_ZN7android11AudioRecordC1E14audio_source_tj14audio_format_tjRKNS_8String16EjPFviPvS6_ES6_j15audio_session_tNS0_13transfer_typeE19audio_input_flags_tiiPK18audio_attributes_t
```

**After Demangling:-**

```
android::AudioRecord::AudioRecord(audio_source_tunsigned intaudio_format_tunsigned intandroid::String16&unsigned intvoid (*)(intvoid*void*)void*unsigned intaudio_session_tandroid::AudioRecord::transfer_typeaudio_input_flags_tintintaudio_attributes_t*)
```

**then what will the** typedef void (**AudioRecordInitNew**) =??

Comment: Use `c++filt` to demangle symbol names (it's included with the NDK).

Comment: I have already demangled it but the problem is how to define that function with parameters

Comment: Not sure I understand the purpose of this `typedef` and how it's supposed to map to the `AudioRecord` constructor.

Comment: basically i want the constructor only , can you write simple constructor for the above mangled function?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Create a function pointer to the constructor? That's not supported in C++.

Comment: Actually i want to call this function from my android java class and for that i am using JNI. Now i am stuck as i do not have the constructor to call this function.This fuction belongs to Libmedia.so which is a system library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157898/discussion-between-japanjot-singh-and-michael).

Comment: Android doesn't allow access to private libraries, so even when you do figure out how to declare the function you won't be able to load it on modern devices.